What type and size Torx bit to remove a Baofeng mic and speaker cover plate?
What type of driver or Torx wrench do I need to remove the 5 Torx-type button-head screws (marked with red dots) in this photo?

I need to remove it in order to slightly enlarge the hole over the microphone. I'm getting complaints of low audio into a local repeater, unless I put my mouth directly over and close to this mic hole, and talk very loudly.
I read that about the only solution to increase my audio level is to slightly enlarge this small hole over the microphone by drilling from the back.
What type of tool is needed to remove these five screws marked with small red dots?
This is a Baofeng UV-5RV2+.

I just sized the screws on my UV-5R MK3X and my standard T6 (T6H actually, but the lack of center pin on the screw head makes no matter) bit fits perfectly. I think it's safe to assume that the same screws are used on your model, but YMMV.
As an aside, I find my Klein Tools 32717 kit (approx $30) perfect for this hobby: Hex, Torx, Phillips, flat, Robertson, triangular, pentalobe bits and others too. Have yet to run into a screw that isn't accommodated by it. I'm sure there are competing kits out there too!
